# How to change default font in Windows 7 Home Basic?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

I know, the title seems dumb, but I've tried [this here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-id/windows/change-windows-fonts#1TC=windows-7), and that don't work at all.

After I install an update, a critical update, which I got on 13 August, my notebook gone error, but the update succeed, leave all of my font's gone so, when I do startup, the font looks like this:
[image: there]

And when I search with my phone, found some sites says "try to install some fonts, it'll works", well, it's works, but how can I change default font? If I want to delete a font, it says "the font's in use". The help that Microsoft's web give, is not in my notebook option list.

I'm running on Toshiba - Windows 7 Home Basic SP1, original.

Comment: Even-though this is not the solution, I'd rather save time by just re-installing or repairing windows.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf well, I don't know how to format Windows, without using CD, because they didn't give the CD, so I can't format/re-install that. While repairing Windows seems that I'll need more money than buying the CD.

Comment: Lol go grab a win7 torrent of your version, burn it on a usb/dvd and go into windows repair and that would fix every problem

Comment: It looks like it's a known issue: [MS14-045: Description of the security update for kernel-mode drivers: August 12, 2014](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2982791/en-us)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hassan said, a reinstall of Windows would solve the problem. Installation discs often do not come with a new computer these days but instead you are instructed to make a backup/install discs yourself on the first time use of the computer. If you didn't make those, you would need to buy/get a copy of Windows 7 elsewhere.

Buy anyways, here are some links that seem to have good tips, tricks and information about how to restore the default fonts in Windows 7 in different kinds of situations:

- [How to restore Windows 7 default fonts](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-restore-windows-7-default-fonts/73a8eb3e-3189-4514-b87c-18fcdca4fe26)
- [Windows 7: How to Re-install Default Windows 7 Fonts](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/71464-how-re-install-default-windows-7-fonts.html)
- [How I restored my Windows 7 default fonts](http://www.withsteps.com/404/how-i-restored-my-windows-7-default-fonts.html)
- [How to Reset Windows 7 to its default font for the whole system?](https://superuser.com/questions/39847/how-to-reset-windows-7-to-its-default-font-for-the-whole-system)
- [Windows 7 Font Fix](http://www.deseret-tech.com/journal/windows-7-font-fix/)
- [Remove Custom Fonts in Windows 8](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/05/29/remove-custom-fonts-windows-8/)

Comment: If none of those links will help you solve the problem, reinstall/repair might be a good solution. :)

Comment: Instead of posting a handful of links, it'd be nice to give an actual solution here in case the other links become unavailable (and generally we don't want to send people away for solutions)

Comment: @slhck I didn't pick those links at random. Two of my friends have had problems with the Windows 7 fonts in the past and I picked links to instructions that are close to the solutions that helped them. ;)

Comment: I didn't say you picked  them at random. What I said was that we like a solution here on Super User rather than another link away.